# Program adaptation for Windows CE 6.0

Tags: visual-studio, windows-mobile, windows-ce, barcode-scanner

Hello and thank you for reading my post.

A few years ago, we developed in my company a barcode application for "Windows Mobile 6.5" using "MS Visual Studio 2005".

This application targets the mobile terminal barcode scanner and also makes use of its filesystem (database).

We noticed that manufacturers presently sell barcode terminals ("Datalogic Memor X3" for example) with the OS "Microsoft Windows CE 6.0 Core" or "CE 6.0 Pro".

"How adaptable" is the "Windows Mobile 6.5" application for "Microsoft Windows CE 6.0"? (I understand it might depend on the application itself but I don't know what information to give here. Please ask and I'll give some additional info if necessary).

Does it involve only minor adaptations or is it hard work?

We couldn't try it ourselves because We are having a hard time setting up a correct development environment (IDE, emulator). We don't know which IDE to use. We heard of "MS Visual Studio 2008" but it's an old version of Visual and it's not that easily available.

Do you have some experience regarding these matters?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use to develop WIN-CE exclusively VISUAL STUDIO 2008 other versions no longer support this platform.

I have a lot of work on these types of devices, and for the maintenance and development use only one pc WIN7 + VS2008.

It 'a stable and effective technology.

Develop for Windows Mobile 6.5 or CE 6.0 is identical

Buy or find a version of Visual Studio 2008, for those of us spread over tencnologia WinMobile (CE Mobile 6.X,embedded) is essential to have VisualStudio 2008. 
The versions of VisualStudio 2010 and later do not support the development of compact framework technology. 
With the 2010 and later versions can only develop for the mobile platform WinRT (WindowsPhone and other)

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer.
I am having a hard time getting "MS Visual Studio 2008". I read this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/obloch/archive/2011/03/09/can-i-still-buy-visual-studio-2008.aspx so I'm trying to download "Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry Enterprise" and "Windows Embedded Standard 7 with SP1 - E SKU" because my Microsoft Partner subscription allows me too. My worry is that it's not exactly "Windows Embedded Compact 7"... There is also an evaluation version of "Windows Embedded Compact 7" at this address:
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/downloads.aspx

Comment: Also, Daniele, I'm sorry but I do not understand the last sentence of your answer...

Comment: Correct the last sentence :-)

Comment: in this page http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/downloads.aspx  go to section "Windows Embedded Compact 7" click to  + to expand menu and Download http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=286741 VS2008ProEdition90DayTrial, use it and if after 90 days if you like it you can buy it

Comment: Yes, well we are presently downloading it.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Do you know, by any chance, if "MS Visual Studio 2005" can be used to develop "MS Windows CE" applications? As for us, we do not manage to get a "Windows CE" emulator working from "VS2005"... but maybe we are doing it wrong.

Comment: Yes, VS2005 can used to develop WinCe becouse contains the compact-framework,you do not recommend it, VS2008 is best strategy. I am also on the development of very complex applications I never used the emulator because it is still slow, carefully developed and put many MessageBox to control the flow

Comment: If you think is the case, you can accept my answer as final-), for any other questions you can find me here

Comment: We haven't used the .NET framework to develop the application. Instead, we have used C++ and MFCs...

Answer (score 1):

As known only VS 2005 or 2008 can be used.
Additionally you need the device vendor SDK.
If you didn't use aygshell functions you will have no issue in migration. Otherwise you have to change the windows mobile shell code.
Is the app written in .net or c/c++?

Comment: The app is not written in .NET. It's written in C/C++ with the MFCs.

Comment: As long as you did not use aygshell or other Windows Mobile only functions the code should migrate easily. Just load it into VS2005/2008 and hopefully the wizard migrates the code without hard to fix problems. Or you start a new smart device Windows CE C++/MFC project and then import the code and header files into that new clean project. What processor is used by this CE device?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last question... I didn't write the Windows Mobile program so I'm pretty new to these matters.

Comment: I would like to try with "MS Visual Studio 2005" (if I can avoid purchasing a "MS Visual Studio 2008" license, it's better for me).
Can you tell me what do I have to install in addition to "VS2005" to run, debug and test a "Windows CE" application? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I also have a "MS Visual Studio 2008" trial license... Is there any chance you can advise me better with this more recent IDE?

Comment: You can convert your trial to a full version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442563%28v=vs.90%29.aspx see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26276601/microsoft-visual-studio-2012-new-mobile-phone-project/26292551#26292551. To migrate a project from Windows Mobile to Windows CE 6 you just have to right click the project in Visual Studio Solution Explorer and then select Change Target. Then select "Windows CE" or the OEMs CE platform (the CE SDK needs to be installed to be able to do so). An example for a OEM installed CE SDK: Intermec CV61 CE shows as "iCE CV61 CE" as target.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide a link so that I can download this Intermec SDK you mentioned? Also, once it's installed, can I use the "Sample CE Device" that is available on my system or will there be another emulator available or do I have to download an emulator and which one? Thx

Comment: You should download the SDK for your device (ie Datalogic Memor X3 is at http://www.datalogic.com/eng/support-services/automatic-data-capture/downloads/software-utilities-sw-2.html?search_prod=636). You can run on Sample CE device if you have one for CE6. "the concept of a 'Standard SDK' is no longer supported in Windows Embedded CE 6.0" see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c82999a8-02b1-4cc0-921c-9c8ad0a205a3/standard-sdk-in-wince-60?forum=vssmartdevicesnative