# Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 new mobile phone project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-mobile

I'm new in Visual Studio. Installed Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 (Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL).

Need to create windows mobile 6.5 application. When I go to File > New > Project I cannot find Windows Mobile in the list of templates. I tried installing Windows Mobile 6.5 Development Tool Kit still doesn't show up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need either Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 and better than the Express edition.

Then you need to install the Windows Mobile 6 SDK or the Windows Mobile 6.5.3 DTK.

In Visual Studio 2005/2008 you will see SmartDevice in the list of Project Templates when you start a new project.

A trial of VS2008 can be downloaded at http://downloadfreesoftwaresforpc.blogspot.de/2012/05/visual-studio-2008-professional-edition.html (http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/1/d/81d3f35e-fa03-485b-953b-ff952e402520/VS2008ProEdition90dayTrialENUX1435622.iso)
You can upgrade the trial following MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442563%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a copy of Visual Studio 2008 to do development for Windows Mobile\Windows Embedded Handheld.  Visual Studio 2010 and later only support the new "Windows Phone" OS.